# Why are doctest modules increasing test coverage in pytest?

Tags: python, pytest, doctest

Using pytest for testing coverage, I've noticed that test coverage drastically increased to near 100% for almost all functions, even those without any doctest module in the docstring. A simple example is the function below:

```py
def test(x):
    return x
```

With this:

```sh
>> pytest --cov=test
Name    Stmts Miss Cover
test.py     2    0    0%
```

If I add to `addopts = --doctest-modules` to `setup.cfg`, then I get:

```sh
>> pytest --cov=test
Name    Stmts Miss Cover
test.py     2    1   50%
```

If I reference `test()` in another module, even one that isn't tested, coverage reaches 100% with doctest modules activated, but 0% still without using doctest and just pytest.

Why is this happening? Can I turn this off? My expected behaviour was that coverage would increase solely for functions with doctests in their docstrings.